# Prerequisite to learn blockchain technology?

Tags: blockchain

I am .Net developer with 6+ yrs exp. I want to upgrade to latest technology. May I know blockchain is good option or not? What are all the pre requisite to learn blockchain technology? Out of Bit coin, Ethereum, Hyperledger which one is the best for career prespective? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about Merkle Trees in detail.  There are good books on the technical details of bitcoin ("Bitcoin and Cryptocurrenty Technologies").  Ethereum is an interesting idea; like an immutable code execution onto a blockchain based virtual machine.  There are interesting ideas for contracts, audit, payment, etc.

The business-oriented books and trade press about it are mostly garbage; maybe worse than watching TV shows.  The technical stuff is more to learn.